# meaning of "grapes in my mouth"

Tags: meaning, phrases

Lyrics from The National's *Ada*:

> Stand inside an empty tuxedo with
>   **grapes in my mouth** waiting for Ada

I've not come across the phrase before, nor can I find an attributed meaning.

One of the song meanings forums suggests this means "*unable to talk since one's mouth is full"*

Is that correct, or is it a phrase the song writers have invented?

Comment: You might be interested in the [Song Meanings](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/28772/song-meanings) proposal.

Comment: I'm not sure this was really off topic. I think it was a valid question where the answer would be something like "this is not a commonly used idiom, but something that the song writers wrote or this song specifically".

Comment: @b.roth, which could be "too localized" hence off topic

Answer (score 1):

Maybe he literally just had some grapes in his mouth? ;)